# T-SQL : Bulk Insert with Dynamic Queries just taking into account the path and not the file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, bulk

I have a dynamic query in which the idea is to bulk the content of a CSV file into a table with a fmt file as a formatter.

However, when passing the file and the formatting file as variables in the query the just pass the location of the file and not the location + the file.

This is my query

```
SET @insertDataCache = 'BULK INSERT  '+@IMPORTFILETABLE+' from  '+@FORMATFILE+' WITH (formatfile= "'+@FORMATFILE+'")'
```

This is the output, which does not contain the csv file or the fmt file (just the path):

```
BULK INSERT [kat].[dbo].[MyTable] 
FROM C:\Users\katt\files 
WITH (formatfile = "C:\Users\katt\formatFiles")
```

Many thanks,

Kat

Comment: No one can help you without seeing the entire script. Perhaps you are making errors similar to those found in your previous questions - did you check? And it makes **NO** sense to use the same variable as both the data file name and the format file name.